# Tag system for Django

Tags: django, django-models, tags, tagging, 3nf

I am building a Quiz app where a user (Content Creator or Author) can create quizzes (choice based questions and their solutions) from a specific domain. These quiz can be attempted by other users (Consumers - not yet implemented).

To allow quiz consumers to be able to search questions based on specific domains of their interest (and to add granularity to the quiz content), I am implementing a tagging system attached to the questions.

Here are my models:

```
class question(models.Model):   

    ques_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    ques_text = models.TextField(max_length=1024, blank=False)
    ques_author = models.ForeignKey('author')
    ques_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    ques_dscore = models.IntegerField()
    ques_bloom = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    ques_subject = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    ques_type = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    ques_flags = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ques_quiz = models.ManyToManyField('quiz')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ques_text

class choice(models.Model):

    choice_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    choice_ques = models.ForeignKey('question')
    choice_ans = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    choice_tags = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class answer(models.Model):

    answer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    answer_text = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    answer_ques = models.ForeignKey('question')
    answer_choice = models.ForeignKey('choice')
    answer_tags = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class author(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username


# a table for storing all the tags
class tags(models.Model):

    tags_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tags_text = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tags_text

# table that connects tags with question attached to the tag
# from all the research on the web, it can be infered that
# 3NF tagging (Toxi Solution) is the best way to go
# good for inserts but slow on selects
class tagcon(models.Model):

    tagcon_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tagcon_tags = models.ForeignKey('tags')
    tagcon_ques = models.ForeignKey('question')
```

I have currently applied the 3NF tagging Toxi solution. The issue is that a denormalized system would help in faster selects and a 3NF would be faster inserts but slow searches.

I am confused if I should use ManyToMany field type for tags. Could someone enlighten if it would be better to use a ManyToMany field inbuilt in Django or implement the 3NF system as done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already *exactly* the same as a ManyToManyField. The only difference is that adding the field would give you an explicit accessor from question to tag.

(Note, your models are very odd. There is absolutely no benefit in prefixing every field name with an abbreviated version of the model name; you can only ever access the field via the model anyway, so you would always be doing `question.ques_text`, which is redundant. And you shouldn't be defining your own PK fields unless you have a very good reason.)

Comment: I want to have a handle on Tags, and the method I have implemented gives me that handle - I guess that is what you mean by "explicit accessor" (I am sorry, my language skills are very poor). 

Thanks a lot for checking out the models. This is my first project in Django of this kind and I am making a lot of such mistakes. I will make suitable changes to reflect these suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion I suggest you try these 2 projects
[django-tagging](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tagging).
[django-taggit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-taggit).